# One-mac household, corrupted hard drive, too old for internet recovery

Tags: hard-drive, imac, recovery, hdd

Long story short, a rusty trusty 2009 iMac is in need of saving.

I got a bit overeager with partitioning in my youth, and whilst recently trying to undo the damage I managed to make the HDD unbootable. The dead bigcat wouldn't allow me to boot a USB, and I've long misplaced the original (Snow Leopard, if I recall) install disks. With my current machine I am unable to burn an install disk (lack of CD drive). The 'local' Mac store told me I should just buy something new, but that's currently not within the budget. I've also looked online for any ancient install disks, but there seem to be none for sale nearby, nor do I have friends in this area of the world who can afford Macs/are willing to purchase them. After checking that I indeed managed to destroy my Recovery partition, if it was ever on there, I removed the hard drive to inspect what on earth was going on, and so the current state of the union: a disassembled iMac waiting for a bootable HDD.

The original hard drive is not broken and has been reformatted (blank) for Mac (Journaled). However, since I have no access to a working Mac, I am not sure how to go about reinstalling OS X on it.

Does anyone know of a way to go through with the installation using a Windows machine as a surrogate, or perhaps another method for getting out of this predicament?

Comment: Would buying Snow Leopard media on ebay be an option?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it would, but I'm really hoping not to have to resort to that.

Comment: Or look for a local Mac users group.  Old timers may have Snow Leopard in their App Store (or Lion) and can download it and make you a bootable USB-stick.  If you cannot boot, you need physical media.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Good tip for the local Mac group. Last time I tried to boot it from USB, it refused. However, it booted an install disk (non-Mac one I had lying around), I just have no method to burn such a thing with a full Mac OS installer on there (I could ofc ask someone to do it, but afaik the file size is too big for the average disk you can buy in a store around here/unfortunately I don't know very many CD/DVD-savvy people). Thus I'm mostly looking to see if I can begin the installation through Windows, as it seems the most independent/painless option for my wallet.

Comment: Got a friend with a DVD burner? You could acquire the 10.6 installation iso, put it on a USB drive and take it somewhere with a windows or linux machine to burn it.

Comment: @nofo A USB-stick needs to be absolutely correctly made for a Mac to boot on it.  Get a more experienced user with a functional mac to help you.

Comment: @Scottmeup 10.6 doesn't fit on a standard sized DVD, most people around me aren't savvy enough to burn a dual layer DVD. I'll see if I can find someone though.

Comment: Roughly, what part of the world are you in?  There are many options, but it will help to know where you are to point you in the right direction.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Noted, indeed. My problem is the following: I don't have experienced users or functional Macs around either. Otherwise I'd have booted up their Recovery long ago, jammed in a USB to SATA cable with my HDD and installed the heck out of their version of OS X on this thing already.

Comment: @Allan Europe, but the very east of it, so it doesn't really count :) I purchased the Mac in a different country and local iWhatever stores are reluctant to help with something this old.

Comment: @nofo If you were more experienced I would suggest burning a Ubuntu DVD and boot on that to investigate.  Given the circumstances just bite the bullet and repurchase Snow Leopard or the latest OS your iMac will run .  $19.95 from https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Actually, I did investigate with an Ubuntu DVD, that's how I know an install disk *would* work. So I'm trying to find a workaround to ordering it due to financial constraints (if there's another method available, the $25+$S&H can find a better home). So, to rephrase: I currently need to install OS X, no install DVD, seemingly non-working USB ports on Mac during boot.
Otherwise I guess I'll just have to wait till I bump into a person with a Mac.